# trouble setting dialog positive button

Tags: android, android-xml, android-dialog

I create my Dialog as:

```
// custom dialog
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.add_taste_dialog);       
dialog.setTitle("Add Taste");
```

then I try and set the positive button with:

```
dialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.addtaste, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {




            }
        });
```

Eclipse give me this error:

```
The method setPositiveButton(int, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){}) is undefined for the type Dialog
```

I was following the android developers references here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Comment: May be you need provide full code for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If u r using custom xml layout for dialog. then why don't u not putting Positive button in your custom layout? Just put button in dialog xml file and do the stuff on its click event.

```
Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonOK);
        // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
        dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
```

Comment: I get this error: The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (new OnClickListener(){})

Answer (score 0):

As the error message indicates, the `setPositiveButton` method is not defined for the `Dialog` class. However, it is defined for the `AlertDialog.Builder` class:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
builder.setTitle("Add Taste")
builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.addtaste, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
          //code goes here
        }
}
AlertDialog dialog = builder.create()
```

If the layout you provide to your dialog is more than a standard `AlertDialog` can accomodate, you can use your current code combined with the dialog class's `findViewById(int id)` method to find your button, provided that you have included a button in the layout you add. Otherwise, you can add a button using the `addContentView(View view, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params)` method.

Here is the reference for the dialog class to investigate those methods: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html

Good luck!

Comment: If I use the dialog builder can I still set the content view to my custom xml? dialog.setContentView(R.layout.add_taste_dialog);

Comment: @Mike You can add `your_custom_xml` but with another call `setView(your_inflated_view)` where `View your_inflated_view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_custom_xml, root)` . I guess you can get alone the inflater.